# Does running Ethereum Wallet support the network?

Tags: mining, wallets, network, solo-mining

If I keep the Ethereum Wallet open, am I helping the network? Am I mining?

Answer (score 1):

No, you are just syncronizing to other peers and updating your blockchain state.